# Calculating the Residue of $f(z)=\frac{z(e^z-1)\cos(z)}{\sinh^3(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, residue-calculus

I need to calculate the residue at $z=0$ for the following function:

$$f(z)=\frac{z(e^z-1)\cos(z)}{\sinh^3(z)}$$

Here I'm trying to see what kind of singular point is $z=0$ and I would say that it is a pole of order 3, however someone told me that if it is also a Zero, then it decrease the order of its pole nature. So it would actually be a pole of order 2 but I have no idea if that if accurate.

Someone has an idea ?

Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, the factor $z$ and the factor $e^z-1$ each provide $z=0$ as a zero with order $1$ each. So, the order of the pole is $3-2=1$. So, to compute the residue, you only need to multiply by $z^1$ and take limit $z\to0$.

Comment: @owl are you sure about this method, it is the first time I have seen someone classify singular points in this way.

Comment: If $\nu_a(f)\in\mathbb{Z}$ denotes the order of the factor $z-a$ in $f$, then in general $\nu_a(fg)=\nu_a(f)+\nu_a(g)$. In your case $\nu_0(f)=\nu_0(z)+\nu_0(e^z-1)+\nu_0(\cos(z))+\nu_0(1/sinh^3(z))=1+1+0-3=-1$. So, $z=0$ is a pole of order $1$ (a zero of order $-1$ if you wish).

Comment: I understand your reservations, but @owl's method is valid. This is perhaps more obvious if we write$$f(z)=\frac{z(z+z^2/2+\cdots)(1-z^2/2+\cdots)}{(z+z^3/6+\cdots)^3}=\frac1z\frac{(1+z/2+\cdots)(1-z^2/2+\cdots)}{(1+z^2/6+\cdots)^3}.$$(This also makes obvious, by the way, that the residue is $1$.)

Comment: @owl that's incredible, I never saw this before, do you have a name for this method?

Comment: It is one of the properties of multiplicity, (or order, or index, or valuation, whichever name is used depending on the context). The proof is an easy exercise. If $f$ and $g$ have $z-a$ as a factor of order $m, n\in\mathbb{Z}$, respectively, then (probably the definition that you use) there are analytic (at $z=a$) $F,G$ such that $f(z)=(z-a)^mF(z)$, $g(z)=(z-a)^nG(z)$ and $F(a),G(a)$ are non-zero. Then, $f(z)g(z)=(z-a)^{m+n}F(z)G(z)$. Since $F(a)G(a)\neq0$, then $fg$ has $z-a$ with order $m+n$.

Comment: @owl ok I got you, thank you so much for this method, it will definitely help me out !

Comment: `Residue[z*(Exp[z] - 1)*Cos[z]/(Sinh[z]^3), {z, 0}]` the residue is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working out the cefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent series gives the answer right away. Note that $$\frac{1}{\sinh^3z}=\frac{8e^{3z}}{(e^{2z}-1)^3}$$ $$=\frac{8(1+3z+...)}{8z^3+...}$$ so your whole expression is $$\frac{z(z+z^2/2!+...)(1-z^2/2!+...)8(1+3z+...)}{8z^3+...}$$ $$=\frac{8z^2(1+...)}{8z^3(1+...)}=z^{-1}++...$$